# Docker Node App Postgres Error "Connection terminated unexpectedly"

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, node-postgres

I'm trying to Dockerize a Node API and getting error only in the Dockerized app. Outside of Docker, `node server.js` works fine without any issues. Using `docker-compose up`, I get the following error after 10 mins with or without API calls:

```
api    | [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
api    | listening on port 3000
api    | API is ready
api    | Error: Connection terminated unexpectedly
api    |     at Connection.<anonymous> (/api/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:255:9)
api    |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:427:28)
api    |     at Connection.emit (events.js:321:20)
api    |     at Connection.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:485:12)
api    |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/api/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:139:10)
api    |     at Socket.emit (events.js:333:22)
api    |     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:485:12)
api    |     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1201:12)
api    |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
api    | [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /api
ADD . /api
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g nodemon
EXPOSE 3000
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  api:
    container_name: api
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/api
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /api
    command: nodemon server.js
```

server.js

```
...
    try {
      let pgDbConfig;
      pgDbConfig = {
        host: '<host>',
        user: '<dbuser>',
        password: '<dbpass>',
        port: 5432,
        database: '<dbname>',
        max: 20,
        idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
        connectionTimeoutMillis: 2000
      };

      pgPool = new Pool(pgDbConfig);

      // the pool will emit an error on behalf of any idle clients it contains if a backend error or network partition happens
      pgPool.on('error', (err, client) => {
        console.error('Unexpected error on idle pg client', err, client);
      });

      // trying to use error listener after the connect
      pgPool.on('connect', () => {
        pgPool.on('error', err => console.log(err));
      });

      console.log('API is ready');

    } catch(exception) {
      console.error('API is not ready');
      process.exit(1);
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I change the way I explain answer:
You basically need Postgres service, in your image you don't have it, you are basically using node image without running Postgres database.

Try this docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  api:
    container_name: api
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/api
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /api
    command: nodemon server.js
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.4
    ports:
      - "35432:5432"
```

Edit 1

Host machine

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  api:
    container_name: api
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/api
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /api
    command: nodemon server.js
```

Comment: I'm connecting to a remote postgres server (outside of the local machine or Docker)

Comment: Ok i edit answer when you use host machine, try now

Comment: Thanks! Trying it now, will report back shortly :)

Comment: What you input in pgDbConfig for host?

Comment: Database credentials to connect to Postgres running on AWS RDS.

Comment: i am using a separate docker pg image but still get this error